# ggplot2 overlay two plots, one legend with manual color selection

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have the following code:

```
FXX_03_Data_8To11_byAgeRange <- structure(list(F20_AgeRange = c("26 - 30",    "31 - 35", "36 - 40", 
                            "41 - 45", "46 - 50", "51 - 55", "56 - 60"),
                            n_Count = c(5L,13L, 59L, 110L, 52L, 14L, 2L),
                            Prozent = c(2, 5.1, 23.1, 43.1,20.4, 5.5, 0.8)),
                            .Names = c("F20_AgeRange", "n_Count", "Prozent"),
                            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                            row.names = c(NA, -7L))

FXX_03_Data_byAgeRange <- structure(list(F20_AgeRange = c("18 – 25", "26 - 30", "31 - 35", 
                            "36 - 40", "41 - 45", "46 - 50", "51 - 55", "56 - 60"),
                            n_Count = c(3L,12L, 25L, 65L, 118L, 58L, 19L, 4L),
                            Prozent = c(1, 3.9, 8.2, 21.4, 38.8, 19.1, 6.2, 1.3)),
                            .Names = c("F20_AgeRange", "n_Count", "Prozent"),
                            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                            row.names = c(NA, -8L))


ggplot() + 
geom_bar(data = FXX_03_Data_8To11_byAgeRange, aes(x = F20_AgeRange, y = Prozent, fill = "Parents 8 to 11"), stat = "identity", width = 0.4, position = position_nudge(x = 0.25)) +
geom_bar(data = FXX_03_Data_byAgeRange, aes(x = F20_AgeRange, y = Prozent, fill = "Parents accumulated"), stat = "identity", width = 0.4, position = position_nudge(x = - 0.25))
```

This results in the following plot: [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roZoL.png)

[image]

Now how do i change the colors of the bars? I know when i move fill out of aes it will let me define a color, but then i loose the legend....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a more `ggplot`-like approach: Merge and tidy both `data.frame`s, and then pass a single `data.frame` to `ggplot` and use aesthetics to map groups to visual properties.

```
library(tidyverse)
full_join(
    FXX_03_Data_8To11_byAgeRange, FXX_03_Data_byAgeRange,
    by = "F20_AgeRange",
    suffix = c(".8To11", ".accumulated")) %>%
    gather(Group, Prozent, starts_with("Prozent")) %>%
    mutate(Group = sub("Prozent\\.", "", Group)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(F20_AgeRange, y = Prozent, fill = Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("8To11" = "red", "accumulated" = "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect, my .R doesn'T know about `position = "dodge2"` but i replaced this by `position = position_dodge(1)`, Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked @xBarns; I'm running `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000` from GitHub, not sure when/if [`position_dodge2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) got introduced in the CRAN version.

Comment: Update: `position_dodge2` is part of `ggplot` version 3.0.0 which got published on CRAN three days ago. So hot off the press (unless you've been running the development version from GitHub).